Matplotlib polar chart not showing all xy-ticks

Issue 1: The x-ticks (pie pieces) aren't ordered from 0 to 24 (my bad, should be 1)
Issue 2: all y-ticks (rings) aren't showing
Issue 3: Someone seems to have eaten a part of the polar chart ...
I expect to see 31 rings, and 24 "pie pieces".

Please Do not post image of code

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='polar')

ax.set_xticks(np.arange(1, 25) * np.pi / 12) 
ax.set_xticklabels([str(number) for number in range(1, 25)])

ax.set_yticks(range(1, 32)) 
ax.set_yticklabels([str(number) for number in range(1, 32)])

ax.grid(True)

ax.scatter(np.pi / 12 * 24, 31)  

ax.set_ylim(0, 32)

plt.show()



Added fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,20)) to make it larger for clarity, just in case someone has the same issue with the bunched up numbers.

Please add some explanation to your answer.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Generate 24 evenly spaced points around the circle.
# The points range from 0 to 2*pi radians (a full circle) 
# and exclude the endpoint to avoid duplication at 2*pi = 0.

hours = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 24, endpoint=False)
## These are just the number of days of a month.
days = np.arange(1, 32)  # 31 days

# Now let's plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': 'polar'}, figsize=(8, 8))

# Here I am plotting a circle for each day, that is 31
for day in days:
    ax.plot(hours, np.full_like(hours, day), label=f"Day {day}" if day == 1 else None)

# Now, Let's add spokes for each hour
for hour in hours:
    ax.plot([hour, hour], [1, 31], color='gray', linestyle='--', alpha=0.6)

# We can format it further
# This should set the 0 at the North
ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
# For clockwise direction
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
# Maximum radius
ax.set_rmax(31)

# Add radial ticks
ax.set_rticks([10, 20, 30]) 
# add hourly ticks
ax.set_xticks(hours)
# add hour labels
ax.set_xticklabels([f"{int(h)}h" for h in np.linspace(0, 23, 24)])

plt.show()

